# The volume slider graphic sometimes shows up, sometimes doesn't

Tags: volume-control

That volume slider graphic thing kind of disappeared. I'm not talking about the volume icon in the system tray, but the one that quickly flashes in and out when you press the volume control keys on your keyboard. Interestingly, sometimes, very rarely though, it does show up, but most of the times it doesn't. And I don't know what is causing this erratic behaviour. Can this be fixed?

Here's what I'm talking about (this is not mine, just a picture I pulled off the Web):

[image: volume control]

PS: I'm using the Gnome Classic desktop environment in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out 2 ways to do it:

#### 1.

Go to **System Settings > Sound** and un-check and re-check the check-mark box shown below:

[image]

#### 2.

Open Terminal and execute:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound visible true
```

Hope it works! : )

Comment: No, this did not help. This has probably something to do with the fact that I'm using the Gnome Classic desktop environment in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: OP  is likely talking about the `notify-send` transparent notification thing, not the sound icon itself

Comment: Then you should have to find something in notify-sned to make it wok somehow. ; )